# how do I find the location of mysql drivers on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, terminal, grep, find, mysql

MariaDB is installed on a remote CentOS 7 server.  How can I find the location of the nearest equivalent to `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8.jar` in the server's file system?

`grep` seems to only search file contents.  The `find` examples I have researched have to do more with exact file names or owner names or file extensions.  I want to find files that might have something like `mysql-connector-java` in their names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find / -mount -name '*mysql-connector-java*' -print
```

the `-mount` predicate is so that `find` skips searching virtual filesystems like `/proc` and `/sys` (useless to search) and other things that might be mounted like network-mounted filesystems (which could make it really slow!), but you can omit it if you want to search absolutely everything.

Answer (score 0):

Most systems have a `locate` database which is updated every night. This does a `find` over the whole system and stores the result in an optimized database.

In this case `locate mysql-connector-java` should have given an answer quicker than the `find` solution.

Note that `locate` will only show files that are findable by every user, so files in protected directories won't be shown.